# Azure Automation Invoke-Sqlcmd : Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, powershell-3.0

I want to run an automation runbook to create a new database for each user and add them as a db_owner on their databases, but after I run the script I got this error `"Invoke-Sqlcmd : Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'. At line:94 char:14 + ... Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $databaseServereInstance -D ... + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ + CategoryInfo : InvalidOperation: (:) [Invoke-Sqlcmd], SqlException + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlExceptionError,Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.PowerShell.GetScriptCommand"` for all users i tried to add as a db_owner.

Locally, the same code is working... only in Azure Automation runbook it's not working.

Below is my code.

```
$databaseServereInstance = '' This are filled i only removed it.
$sourceDatabaseName = ''
$azureRg = ''
$sourceServer = ''

# Login to Azure AD PowerShell With Admin Account
$connectionName = "AzureRunAsConnection" 
$servicePrincipalConnection=Get-AutomationConnection -Name $connectionName         
# Now you can login to Azure PowerShell with your Service Principal and Certificate

Connect-AzAccount -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint
Connect-AzureAD -TenantId $servicePrincipalConnection.TenantId -ApplicationId $servicePrincipalConnection.ApplicationId -CertificateThumbprint $servicePrincipalConnection.CertificateThumbprint


#Get-AzureADGroup
[String]$groupname = 'fiduciagad'
[Microsoft.Open.AzureAD.Model.Group]$getGroup = Get-AzureADGroup | Where { $PSItem.DisplayName -eq $groupname }
Write-Output $getGroup.DisplayName

if($getGroup -ne $null)
{
  #Get-AzureADGroupMember
  Get-AzureADGroupMember -ObjectId $getGroup.ObjectId | ForEach-Object -Process `
  {
     [String]$userPrincipalName = $PSItem.UserPrincipalName
     Write-Output $userPrincipalName
     [String]$givenName = $PSItem.GivenName
     Write-Output $givenName
     
    
         [String]$devUserPrincipalNameDatabase = "$($sourceDatabaseName)-DevDB-$($givenName)"
         [String]$targetDatabase = (Get-AzSqlDatabase -Name "$devUserPrincipalNameDatabase" -ResourceGroupName $azureRg -ServerName $sourceServer).DatabaseName
         
       
             #Remove source database for each user in a group
             Remove-AzSqlDatabase -ResourceGroupName $azureRg -ServerName $sourceServer -DatabaseName $devUserPrincipalNameDatabase

             #Copy source database for each user in a group and make the user db_owner
             
             New-AzSqlDatabaseCopy -ResourceGroupName $azureRg -ServerName $sourceServer -DatabaseName $sourceDatabaseName `
               -CopyResourceGroupName $azureRg -CopyServerName $sourceServer -CopyDatabaseName $devUserPrincipalNameDatabase

             [String]$query = "
                -- Add contained Azure AD user 
                CREATE USER [$($userPrincipalName)] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = dbo;   
                -- Add user to role(s) in db 
                ALTER ROLE db_owner ADD MEMBER [$($userPrincipalName)]; 
                "
             [String]$getDbAzSqlAaccessToken = (Get-AzAccessToken -ResourceUrl 'https://database.windows.net/').Token
             Write-Output $getDbAzSqlAaccessToken    
             Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $databaseServereInstance -Database $devUserPrincipalNameDatabase -AccessToken $getDbAzSqlAaccessToken ` -query $query
  }
} 
else
{
  Write-Verbose -Message "AzureAD Group could not be found..."
}
```

Answer (score 0):

•   Please ensure that the ServerInstance must be the full SQL Server name, not just the part that is declared as a variable. Since, locally, the server instance name might be picked up automatically since you are authenticating with first an AAD user.

•   Also, check whether the AAD user through which you are signing into the database locally has the required permissions that your database needs. For example,

```
 CREATE USER [<identity -name>] FROM EXTERNAL PROVIDER;
 ALTER ROLE db_datareader ADD MEMBER [<identity-name>];
 ALTER ROLE db_datawriter ADD MEMBER [<identity-name>];
 ALTER ROLE db_ddladmin ADD MEMBER [<identity-name>];
```

•   Here, < identity-name > is the name of the managed identity in Azure AD. If the identity is system-assigned, the name is always the same as the name of your App Service app. Also, the AAD user might not be added to the SQL DB that you are trying to connect or the AAD user through which you are running this script in Azure runtime doesn’t have AAD server admin role. You just need to add AAD user in Azure SQL DB.

Please find the below links for more information: -

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell#create-contained-database-users-in-your-database-mapped-to-azure-ad-identities

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/133709/login-failed-for-user-39lttoken-identified-princip.html

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I found a solution:

In **Role and Assignments** in **Azure Active Directories,** I added the role **Directory Reader** for **AzureAutomationAccount** and for the **AzureSqlServer**

After that, everything has been working.

Answer (score 0):

Exactly, when you are trying to assign permissions to Azure AD identities (users, groups, service principals, managed identities) to an Azure SQL Database (or Azure Synapse-Serverless-SQL-Endpoint / Azure Synapse-Dedicated-SQL-Endpoint) you need to ensure that your service principal you are using to set the Azure AD permissions to your database has the following:

1. Read access to Azure AD (to verify the identities we would like to grant access to do exist in Azure AD)
   **=>** *IAM Role* "**Directory Reader**" in Azure Active Directory
2. In Azure portal is set as:

   - "**Azure Active Directory admin**" (in *Azure SQL DB*)
   - "**SQL Active Directory admin**" (in *Azure Synapse*)
3. Connect to Azure SQL Database (where you want to grant access to) using "**[Azure AD Authentication][1]**".

So each user which should grant access to Azure AD identities require both of the just mentioned access rights.
To be able to grant access for Azure AD identities the authorizing user needs to use Azure AD authentication (step 2. *opens the door* for the first user on *a fresh database* without any Azure AD users authorized yet).

---

I also had the error `"Invoke-Sqlcmd : Login failed for user '<token-identified principal>'"`. In my case the issue was a typo in the line of my `Invoke-SqlCmd` statement. If the parameter list is not correct or contains typos this error occurred. In the code example of the initial post

> `Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $databaseServereInstance -Database $devUserPrincipalNameDatabase -AccessToken $getDbAzSqlAaccessToken`  -query $query`

I think the problem is the line break apostrophe character "**`**" before the command is completed (`-query $query` is not in a new line, but even after the line break apostrophe. This caused confusion in my powershell script (using Azure DevOps Pipelines for CI).

**My solution was to write the whole Invoke-SqlCmd command in one line without aprostrophes and without line breakes.**

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $databaseServereInstance -Database $devUserPrincipalNameDatabase -AccessToken $getDbAzSqlAaccessToken -query $query
```